# angular complaining about missing properties in return data set

Tags: angular

I'm getting this error:

> ERROR in src/app/services/widgets.service.ts:47:5 - error TS2322: Type 'UserActivity | { Users: { name: string; id: number; tName: string; tId: number; bCode: string; bName: string; bId: number; userType: string; }[]; TotalRecords: nu mber; HasError: boolean; LoadMore: boolean; }[]' is not assignable to type 'UserActivity'.   Type '{ Users: { name: string; id: number; tName: string; tId: number; bCode: string; bName: string; bId: number; userType: string; }[]; TotalRecords: number; HasError: boolean; LoadMore: boolean; }[]' is missing the following properties from  type 'UserActivity': Users, TotalRecords  47     return reportData;

I've defined the following models:

```ts
import { FileValue } from '@apps/pattern-web';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export interface UserActivity {
  Users: FormsUser[];
  TotalRecords: number;
  HasError?: boolean;
  LoadMore?: boolean;
}

export interface FormsUser {
  name: string;
  id: number;
  tName?: string;
  tId: number;
  bCode?: string;
  bName?: string;
  bId?: number;
  userType: string;
}
```

And here's how I try to use these models in my widgets service logic:

```ts
 /**
   * Get User Type Statistics
   * @param searchrange to retrieve.
   * @param tId
   * @param bID
   */
  async getUserStatistics(
    range: string,
    userType: string,
    tId: number,
    bId: number
  ): Promise<UserActivity> {

    const query: UserActivityQuery = {
      UserType: userType,
      BID: bId,
      TID: tId,
      RecordsLoaded: 50,
    };
    const reportData = this.testMode
      ? await this.getDummyData(query)
      : await this.getUserActivity(query);

    return reportData;
  }

 getDummyData(query: UserActivityQuery) {
    return [
      {
        Users:[
          {
            name: "John Doe",
            id: 1,
            tName: "ttorg",
            tId: 3,
            bCode: "mbr",
            bName: "widgetsmbr",
            bId: 2,
            userType: "creator"
          },
          {
            name: "Jane Doe",
            id: 2,
            tName: "ttorg",
            tId: 3,
            bCode: "mbr",
            bName: "widgetsmbr",
            bId: 2,
            userType: "creator"
          }
        ],
        TotalRecords: 2,
        HasError: false,
        LoadMore: false
      }
      ]
  }
```

Im sure it's something simple I can't see what I've done wrong in my dummy data set up.
Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: First of all... getDummyData doesn't return a promise, but you are using await on it? How are you not getting an error about that before anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to notice is the kind of errror , whenever you see a "Type-error" in angular, its mostlikely nothing that actually prevents your programm from being run, but an minor error within Typescript.
Now theres a bunch of wais to locate the error

1. log the type

   console.log(typeof element_name)

This might help you quickly find out why your code is causing a type error by simply asking about it.

2. giving the complaining element the type "any"

this is not a pretty solution and i would only use it to find out whats wrong.

3. QUICKEST -> dissable typescript on that line by adding

   // @ts-ignore

Your error message is essentially saying that type or class of is not assignable to type 'UserActivity' is not assignable to the same type/object 'UserActivity'... so there's probably a minor attribute that you forgot to put somewhere.

Hope this helps <3

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding the fact that `getDummyData` doesn't return a promise, I assume that is a quickly typed question...

If you read the error, it says that an array (of `UserActivity` in this case) is not assignable to `UserActivity`, which is correct. Notice the end in the lines i.e `[]`... which indicates that it is an array `.....boolean; }[]'`

and when you look at what `getDummyData` returns... it is an array, whereas it should be an object. Here again comes the power of typescript... type **EVERYTHING**. You would have gotten useful red squiggly lines in your IDE when actually adding return types.... e.g return type of what `getDummyData` returns...

```
getDummyData(query: UserActivityQuery): Promise<UserActivty> { // assuming it should be a promise
```

and also typed the `dummyData` inside `getDummyData`, i.e

```
return [
  { 
    Users: ......
  }
] as UserActivity; // obviously type mismatch
```

As said, you would have gotten nice red squiggly lines. Type everything and make your life easier :)